# Create view with path relative to taxonomy term

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have multiple content types and would like to create a couple of views to show various content types as sub directory to the term page.

The challenge is that I need to the path to be taxonomy/term/%/content-type1
taxonomy/term/%/content-type2

Tired using tokens in the views path. It didn't work.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to influence filtering Views through URL arguments is to use Contextual filters. For each URL sensitive Contextual filter you get one argument in your URL (separated by `/`).

In your case you need to add a new Contextual Filter of type `Content: Content type` and configure it:
    When the filter value is NOT in the URL
    **Provide default value**
    **Raw value from URL**
    **Path component**: **4**
    When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided
    **Specify validation criteria**
    **Content type**
    **Single ID**
    **Case in path**: **Lowercase**
    More
    **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**

Change the `Path` of your Page from `taxonomy/term/%` to `taxonomy/term/%/%`.

Now when you visit `taxonomy/term/1/article` it will list all articles tagged with the term 1 (I'm assuming you have cloned the default Taxonomy term Views).

---

### Show term names instead of TID in URL

It is possible to pass term names to Views from URL, instead of using term ID numbers. So the URL might look something like: `taxonomy/term/tag1/article`

To achieve that we have to introduce the term name into Views. In this example we cloned the default  Taxonomy term Views, and they only have term ID available.

To introduce more information about the taxonomy term we add a new Relationship. In this case we add **Taxonomy term referenced from field_myvocabulary** (use your Entity reference field referencing the term from the relavant vocabulary).

There are no consequences of this step visible from the outside, but from the inside we have more choices to choose from when adding new Contextual Filters. One of those new choices is **Name** from **Taxonomy term** Category. Add that as a new Contextual Filter and configure it:
    Relationship: field_myvocabulary: Taxonomy term
    **Provide default value**
    **Raw value from URL**
    **Path component**: **2**
    When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided
    **Specify validation criteria**
    **Taxonomy term name**
    Vocabulary: **My Vocabulary**
    **Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values**
    More
    **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**

Rearrange the Contextual filters to have that Name filter first, then the Content type second and you can ignore or remove the original "Has taxonomy term ID" in third place.

Now you can enter `tag1/article` into the Preview and you'll see the results, all with using human-friendly URL bits. `or visit /hub/tag1/article` on your site.

Relationships can introduce duplicate results. If this happens make sure your filters have turned on "Reduce duplicates" option, although you'll probably have to edit your Views **Query settings** and set them **Distinct**.

Be careful about the Case settings and converting spaces to dashes and vice versa. Your term name might be "Best term", and depending on your Contextual filters settings you might need to enter "best term" or "Best-term" etc.

The default Taxonomy term Views renders Taxonomy term in Views Header area. I haven't been able to make it work with the Taxonomy name though. It does work if you keep the ID as the third filter and use path `tag1/article/1`.

But you can solve it (if you need this feature of rendered Taxonomy term in Views Header) with the help of an additional module: [Views taxonomy term name into ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_taxonomy_term_name_into_id) and the patch mentioned there.

You can also use this module to get term name in URL, instead of using a Relationship like explained above ;)

Comment: Yes, prkos. I have cloned taxonomy term. Will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: One question. Should the default contextual filter stay or be removed?

Comment: It should stay, the first Contextual filter will pass on the information about which Taxonomy term to display on the page. That is the first `%` in your URL. The second `%` in your URL is from the second Contextual filter, in your case the content type machine name. So you need them both working to get the pages you want (term pages with content type subpages).

Comment: I see. Thank you. I tried but didn't get it to work the first time. Do you think the fact that pathauto is used to rewrite the url is messing this up? I will keep on trying.

Comment: No, Pathauto aliases don't turn off the original links, so that won't affect it. Every detail in configuration is important, go step by step and make sure you got it right. Does the View work as expected before you add the new Contextual filter? You can test in the Views Preview by entering `1/all` if your Taxonomy term ID is 1 and you left the Exception as default `all` in the second Contextual filter. Did you forget to adjust the Path (added one extra `%`)?

Comment: prkos, thank you very much for your help. You have been a great resource. I will work on it again as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Eureka! It worked. The only limitation now is that the path has to be https://www.domian.com/taxonomy/term/ID/Article 
If I use the pathauto url/aritlce it does not work. Can I use tokens to link to this /Article page. 

Thank you again for your help. You have are AMAZING!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! What exactly do you mean use token to link? Do you mean instead of showing the TID to show the name of the term? It's difficult to say before I know the details of what you'd like to end up with. What would be your ideal path pattern?

Comment: It is working perfectly if I use this path domain.com/taxonomy/term/{{ tid }}/article but not if I use domain.com/termname/article which is the path of the term rewritten with pathauto.

Comment: To be more exact my acutal paths are domain.com/hub/termname/ 

I am thinking my path needs to be /hub/%/%  but for some reason my to contextual filters are not working. Even after changing path from 4 to 3

Comment: I added the term name solution to my answer ;) BTW if you also want `hub/termname` to work on its own, without the content type as third argument, you have to create 2 pages, one for each depth. You can also use Menu option under Page settings to show your subpages as Drupal tabs on the Parent pages.