# Similar content with contextual filter by url

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

There are two types of content (as an example):

1. fruits
2. vegetables

They share the same vocabulary and similar terms.
Catalog structure:

```
-Fruits
--juices
---for children
---for men
---for women
-Vegetables
--juices
---for children
---for men
---for women
```

Url path for mango: /fruits/mango

I want to show similar vegetable juices for children in the fruit node, if the path matches the difference only with the first part of the url.

Need to show similar content if url path matches /%/juices/for-children

I found this solution ([Create view with path relative to taxonomy term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263191/create-view-with-path-relative-to-taxonomy-term/263195)), but it doesn’t help me, because the paths change there at the end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The linked URL is the correct approach.  Use **Path component** to control which part of the path is the argument.  /fruits (path component 1)/juices (path component 2)/for-children (path-component 3)

Comment: The problem is that this is not the path of the term itself.

Node has a path: /fruits/mango.
I need a contextual filter by url term path.

Or am I misunderstanding...

Comment: Are you adding this as a block in Views?  You can use contextual filters on blocks, and you can set the block to display on whatever pages you want at `/admin/structure/blocks/`.

Comment: You might want to clarify the structure of both nodes and terms (like put in detail their fields, their relationships). Because currently, I can't tell what is what (what is "juices"? Is it a taxonomy? "for children"? Is that a term? or a boolean on another term?). I also would not be too fixated on "filter by path", as there might be other ways to do this that don't involve paths.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining correctly right away.

Vocabulary: catalog

`-Fruits
--juices
---for children
---for men
---for women
-Vegetables
--juices
---for children
---for men
---for women`
For example, I have fruit mango, that relative to term ("fruits" -> "juices" -> "for children").

I have vegetable carrot that relative to term ("vegetables" -> "juices" -> "for children").

Now I want carrot to show as related content to mango.

Comment: I add structure to main question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve this problem was by installing the module https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree

And then I manually match the related terms together. Like in previous versions in drupal (6,7)

Then created a view.

Relationship:

- taxonomy term (with limit by vocabulary)
- field_related_terms (the field you have created with Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget)

Contextual Filter:
taxonomy term: field_related_terms (with relationship)

When the filter value is NOT in the URL

- **Provide default value**
- **Term id from URL**
- **Load default filter for related taxonomy blocks**
- **Filter by items that contain any of the terms**

In section more:
**Allow multiple values**

This is how it works. But how to achieve this only in a view without a module and without manual matching of related terms, I did not understand.